# Plotting two isosurface objects in one figure with different colormaps

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to draw two boxes in one figure in `MATLAB`, using 3D `isosurface` function .

---

### Definition of Boxes

So the following code is for defining the "interior" region of two different boxes with value 1.

```
[x, y, z] = meshgrid (-3:0.1:3, -3:0.1:3, -3:0.1:3);
BoxA = (x(:) >= -2 & x(:) <= 1) & (y(:) >= -2 & y(:) <= 1) & (z(:) >= -2 & z(:) <= 1);
BoxA = reshape(BoxA, size(x));
BoxB = (x(:) >= -1 & x(:) <= 2) & (y(:) >= -1 & y(:) <= 2) & (z(:) >= -1 & z(:) <= 2);
BoxB = reshape(BoxB, size(x));
```

---

### Plot

And here is a code for drawing the above boxes on the same figure.

```
figure; hold on;
colormap('autumn');
isosurface(BoxA,0.5);
colormap('winter');
isosurface(BoxB,0.5);
legend('BoxA', 'BoxB');
alpha(0.3); hold off;
```

I defined two different colormaps `autumn` and `winter`, but what I only got was two ambiguous boxes with the same colormap `winter`.

Some might think `isosurface` is an overkill for drawing 3D box, but I also would like to do the similar work for 3D ellipsoids.

Is there anyone to give any advice?

Comment: Yes, `isosurface` is overkill, even for ellipsoids. The `colormap` is applied to the figure, not to individual elements in it. You'll have to modify the color of the patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `colormap` applies a color map to the figure (the whole window). Since a few years ago, it is possible to apply a different color map to each axes within a window, by explicitly giving the `colormap` function an axes handle. But it is not possible to assign a color map to individual components within the axes.

Each polygon in a patch (or actually each vertex) can be assigned its own color. It is also possible to assign a single color to all polygons. This is probably what you're after.

This is one way of modifying the patches you create:

```
figure; hold on;

h1 = patch(isosurface(BoxA,0.5));
h1.EdgeColor = 'none';
h1.FaceColor = [1,0,0];
h1.FaceAlpha = 0.7;

h2 = patch(isosurface(BoxB,0.5));
h2.EdgeColor = 'none';
h2.FaceColor = [0,1,0];
h2.FaceAlpha = 0.5;

legend('BoxA', 'BoxB');
```

Instead of using `isosurface` without an output argument (which creates the patch object), we're using it with one output argument. This output is the information to draw the patch object. We pass this into the `patch` function, which in turn returns a handle to the patch object. We need this handle to modify the patch.